# Unable to instantiate a Weka class in MATLAB

Tags: java, matlab, machine-learning, weka

I'm trying to convert data `X` in MATLAB into a Weka `Instance` class.  I'm using Weka 3.7.5 and MATLAB 7.10 (2010a).

I've tried the following:

```
javaaddpath([WEKA_HOME 'weka.jar']);
import weka.core.*;

N = 3;
inst = Instance( N );
```

And I receive the error

```
??? No constructor 'weka.core.Instance' with matching signature found.
```

When I type `which Instance`, it is able to find this class.  Also, this form of the constructor agrees with the one documented [here](http://bio.informatics.indiana.edu/ml_docs/weka/weka.core.Instance.html).

I'm inexperienced with calling Java from MATLAB, so it's likely I'm missing something simple here.  Thanks!

Updates:

1. Tried casting N to an int32, but no luck, still same error.
2. I tried this with an older version of Weka ( ver 3.5.8 ) and it worked.  Can't explain why though.
3. I found updated [documentation](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/) :    which tells me that `Instance` is now an interface rather than a class like it was in the documentation I was looking at.  So I guess my question is now,  can I instantiate this like I do a class?   Sorry for confusing this initially..

Comment: How do you define `N`? What if you convert it to integer with `int32(N)`?

Comment: Good suggestion,  but still same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Use class `DenseInstance` instead of `Instance`. It's an implementation of the `Interface` in 3.6.

Comment: This fixes the problem for me, using weka 3.7.6.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A wild guess:

Wekas API suggest that there are 3 constructors:

> Instance(double weight, double[] attValues)
>   Instance(Instance instance)
>   Instance(int numAttributes)

So if you are using the last one, cast 3 to int32 first, like that:

> inst = Instance( int32(N) );

Frankly, I haven't checked it, so  I can't be sure in 100%

Update: (Following question edit)
You cannot instantiate an interface!
An interface is like a contract in SE between the user and the programmer. It is not a concrete implementation

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inst = javaObject('weka.core.Instance', N);
```